# How to write proper do..while loop?

Tags: c, loops, cs50

for some reason this code throws an error when I'm trying to compile it. What is wrong, can you tell me please?
I'm taking a CS50 course and it's actually the first assignment.

The program has to prompt the user for input until the condition is false.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int n;

do
{
    n = get_int();
}
while ( n < 0 || n > 23 );
```

This is the Error:

```
pyramid.c:6:1: error: expected identifier or '('
do
^
pyramid.c:10:1: error: expected identifier or '('
while ( n < 0 || n > 23 );
```

Comment: And what error is it? I'm guessing it complains about the lack of an `int main(void)`

Comment: A tail recursive function. => []

Comment: Is your missing `main` function intentional? If yes, please remember that code examples should be complete ([mcve]). If no, then I suggest you start learning with basic C tutorial.

Comment: @user694733 Thank you!

Comment: There's a [cs50 stack exchange site](http://cs50.stackexchange.com/), if you're interested.

Comment: It thinks you are trying to declare a function or variable named "do".  The error messages for gross syntax mistakes are never very clear, the compiler just can't guess what you try to do.  Statements like do-while must appear inside a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the generic example of using `do {...} while();` loop in C. 
cs50 is not the standard C header, this is homecooked for the students who take cs50 course.

You should check the `get_int()`; definition in the cs50.h header file.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int number;

    // Do while loop is executed at least once
    do
    {
      printf("Enter a number from 0-23: ");
      scanf("%d", &number);

    }
    while(number < 0 || number > 23);

    printf("Number = %d\n",number);

    return 0;
}
```